# NSTableView steals -mouseUp: from mouse drag sequence started inside an NSView sibling

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, drag, mouseup

`NSView` *A* contains an `NSTableView` (in an `NSScrollView`), a child `NSView` *B*, and listens to mouse events by implementing `-mouseDown/Dragged/Up:`. `NSView` *B* implements neither of these methods, so the original `NSResponder` ones should forward the corresponding messages to its next responder (parent view).

When the mouse is clicked inside, dragged from `NSView` *B*, and released over any object other than the `NSTableView`, the whole dragging sequence (down/dragged/up) is sent to the parent view normally.

**If, however, the mouse is released over the `NSTableView`, the `-mouseUp:` message is never sent to the parent view**. Instead, it is stolen by the NSTableView.

This behaviour can be changed to normal by subclassing `NSView` *B* and implementing the `-mouseUp:` message so that it simply passes the event to its next responder (precisely what the original NSResponder method is supposed to do).

Observed on OSX 10.7.4/Xcode 4.4. A test project can be downloaded from here: http://www.filefactory.com/file/41ung2am0aax/n/TestDragging_zip

Is this an expected behaviour or a bug?

Comment: This might be answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744161/nsview-does-not-receive-mouseup-event-when-mouse-button-is-released-outside-of - if so, please let me know.